# Facebook Open Graph, Creating a story with an action and more than one object

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When creating an open graph story, I select one action and one object. For example:

```
user created GROUP on MyCoolGroups
```

That's okay for now, but I need to create an action involving TWO or more objects. For example:

```
user invited JOHN to GROUP on MyCoolGroups
```

Where "INVITE" is the action, "JOHN" is an object (a facebook user in this case, which should get notified of this action) and "GROUP" is also a valid open graph object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Did you make any progress on your own?

Comment: It's my understanding that Users cannot be objects in open graph stories.